# Run a script via .plist on login as if in a specific directory

Tags: mac-osx, launchctl, startup-scripts

My .plist file calls a shell script but the script fails because it references other files in the same directory as the script.

Thus the script only runs successfully when I 'cd' to the correct folder.

How can I get the .plist to have this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WorkingDirectory` option:

> **WorkingDirectory <string>**
>
> This optional key is used to specify a directory to chdir(2) to before running the job.

To see all available options, check `launchd.plist` manual page.